# Load Factor in own implementation of a HashTable

Tags: java

As part of one of the experiment problem in datastructure and algorithm I was try to create my Customhashtable having CustomLinkedList[] as a underlying datastructure to avoid collusion(seperate chaining).But when load-factor exceeds.75 ,i'm  stuck on how to map the previous contents to new array with increased size so that index returned will be same with new size,   code for hashing with size = 100

```
public int arrayIndex(String key)
{
   int index = key.charAt(0);

   for(int j = 1;j<key.length;j++)
     {
        int temp = key.charAt(j);
         index = ((index*27)+temp)%100;
     }
}
```

Comment: don't use an index, use a counter to hold the number of populated entries.

Comment: 1) Do yourself a favor and find a more robust hash algorithm.  And only after the full hash value is computed should you "mod" it to the array size.  2) There are cases where the overflow scheme is to enlarge the table while leaving existing elements in place, then "remember" the history of prior sizes and "mod" the hash value by each prior size successively on search, until a match is found.  Less overhead to enlarge, at the expense of slower searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you construct a new hashtable, and the migrate all the data from the old one to the new one.  The load factor is a trigger to tell you when to construct the newer (bigger) table, meaning that the new hashtable will have a larger starting array.

You could (for fun) also add a "min load factor" setting, which would construct a smaller hashtable.  With a solution that had min and max load factors, the initial backing array (which is the only part that the hash selects form) would conceptually tune it's size based on the number of stored items.  Since size is related to performance, this could allow a hashtable to always maintain an acceptable range of performance (by growing and shrinking it's memory footprint).

As far as the calculation of load factor

```
  (in the store routines)

  if (array[index] == null) {
    loadCount++;
  }
  if (loadCount / arraySize > maxLoad) {
    resizeUp(...);
  }

  (in the remove routines)
  if (array[index] is cleared to null) {
    loadCount--;
  }
  if (loadCount / arraySize < minLoad) {
    resizeDown(...);
  }
```

Comment: No, you must create the new array, and then add all items to it, using the normal hashing routines, as the modulus of the hash is probably not going to be identical between arrays.  Generally speaking if (x mod y == 5) then you can't (except in some very special circumstances) know that (x mod z == 5).

Answer (score 0):

In a straight forward implementation, when you increase the size of the backing array in a hash table, the indexes of all the stored elements will change, and you will need to remove elements from your linked lists since elements are unlikely to continue to share the same bucket in the new map.

E.g. Originally we have backing array as:

```
0: [ A ]
1: [ ]
2: [ B, C ]
3: [ D ]
```

Then we increase the backing array and we may end up with:

```
0: [ ]
1: [ ]
2: [ C ]
3: [ ]
4: [ D ]
5: [ A ]
6: [ ]
7: [ B ]
```

Each item in the backing array needs to have its hash and modulo recomputed since it now belongs in a new bucket.  There may be a more optimal method of doing this recalculation or mapping if you use specific backing array sizes, and you can look at existing hash table implementations to see what they do (i.e. the source of java.util.HashMap is readily available), but in general you need to move all elements to their correct bucket.